# htaccess redirect old links to new domain

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I changed my site domain, and want to redirect old urls to new domain

(note: instead of numbers 93, 54 maybe any digit number exists)
the old urls are:

```
http://olddomain.com/
http://olddomain.com/45
http://olddomain.com/p/93
```

the new urls are:

```
http://newdomain.com/
http://newdomain.com/45
http://newdomain.com/p/93
```

I tried this at htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 
RewriteRule  http://newdomain.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\d+)/
RewriteRule (\d+)/ http://newdomain.com/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} p/(\d+)/
RewriteRule p/(\d+)/ http://newdomain.com/p/$1
```

but not worked :(

In addition, there is a choice at cpanel caller Redirects
can I redirect the old links to new by using it.
thanks for help

Comment: if we can redirect any segment(s) written at old links to new links, this will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

It will redirect all pages from the old website to the new website.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just those three you want to redirect, you can do it with an OR in your regex. The below should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(45|p/93|$)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I don't mean exactly 45 and 93. Maybe any digit number will be exist

Comment: See Howlin's answer in that case. You should make this clearer in the question.