# htaccess redirect current url to themselves, but including a subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want all requests to pages without a subfolder to be redirected to the same URL, but including the subfolder (the subfolder does not exist actually, I just need to append it to my url for seo reasons).

```
current.mysite.com
current.mysite.com/pages/some-awesome-page
current.mysite.com/news/category/some-article
```

should be all redirected to

```
current.mysite.com/ru/
current.mysite.com/ru/pages/some-awesome-page
current.mysite.com/ru/news/category/some-article
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017137/htaccess-redirect-old-links-to-new-domain) solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

But I end up getting this:

```
http://current.mysite.com/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/ru/pages
```

This is my htaccess:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://current.site.com/ru/$1 [R=301]

#RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


# END WordPress


</IfModule>
```

How do I accomplish this task?

EDIT:

Thanks to @Croises answer I was able to put it all together, meaning using wordpress htaccess file you need the lines in exact the same order as here (i.e. custom redirect in front of wordpress redirect) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Begin custom redirect 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+ru/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L] 
RewriteRule ^ru(/.*)$ $1 [NC,L] 
# End custom redirect

# Begin Wordpress magic
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# End Wordpress magic

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code (RewriteRule) with:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+ru/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L] 

RewriteRule ^ru(/.*)$ $1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Now it says `Not Found

The requested URL /ru/ was not found on this server.`
I think I should've added this - there is no subfolder 'ru', I just need to append it to my url (seo reasons).

Comment: I'm sorry, the redirect is working, i.e. `http://current.mysite.com/projects` request is redirected to `http://current.mysite.com/ru/projects`, however I receive now:

`Not Found

The requested URL /projects was not found on this server.`
This page is definitely existent.

Comment: I've uncommented Wordpress redirect lines: 
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+ru/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L] 
RewriteRule ^ru(/.*)$ $1 [NC,L] 
</IfModule>`
And now if I hit `http://current.mysite.com/ru/projects` the right page is displayed, however if I hit `http://current.mysite.com/projects` it is displayed too and is not redirected.
I'm sure I'm making some newbie mistakes, sorry!

Comment: I just switched the blocks, meaning put your answer first and after that put the wordpress lines. Working like a charm!

Comment: I've got still one more issue - when applying all the redirection rules I can't login into admin anymore (the login (/wp-admin) page just reloads, without any errors. Right now I'm commenting the redirection rules when I want to log in, then, after administrations, I comment them out, but it's a bit inconvenient.

Comment: Yon can add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin` before the first `RewriteRule`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Had to add 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login.php`
because /wp-admin always redirects to wp-login.php, but your solution works for it aswell. 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login.php`

Comment: You can add only one: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-admin|wp-login)` with test for admin and login.