# Redirect web page visitors with deep links to new domain address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I changed my domain from example.com to example.net and there are lots of people using deep links which I need to redirect.  I saw 3 other posts on SO (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017137/htaccess-redirect-old-links-to-new-domain)) but none seem exactly the same as this problem.

I want to remove any preceding www. but retain any suffix (path).  This is a close as I got but it's not working when a path is added to the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

I have other web domains hosted on this server, so I cannot use catchall rules as show in some other examples

Comment: Do you want to change the URL as well right when you do redirect ?

Comment: The page and query string should be passed through unchanged, Any "www." prefix should be removed.  And the domain name should be changed from example.com to example.net